# What to use for recovery disk when CD is not an option

Tags: storage, read-only, write-protect

I have a computer that has no optical drive and getting on to work with that is very hard(believe me I've tried).

What are some alternatives for recovery media in case the current OS fails?
I have though about a simple USB stick but one can easily confuse that for something else and format it, add whatever they want on it etc. I am looking for something that is read-only and can last a long time without use.

What are some read-only alternatives to CD or optical drives that can last a good while for emergency use?

Comment: Windows supports creating Recovery Media on USB devices.  Your question is really vague.

Comment: @Ramhound, what exactly is vague about the question? OP is looking for a device with [preferably] hardware write-protection mechanism

Comment: @smc - There is the obvious question.  What operating systems are we dealing with.  Perhaps vague was the incorrect word, the question is broad, very broad in its current form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any better option than a USB stick. You could use a CD + a USB CD drive, but that would obviously be more complicated.

About accidentally overwriting the stick: There are USB sticks with a pyhsical write protect switch - you could use one of those. Just search for "usb stick write protect".
Or just put the USB stick into a sealed envelope with a fat warning "USB recovery stick - emergency use only" :-).

Comment: "USB recovery stick - emergency use only" thats like challenging someone to mess with the stick :p

Answer (score -2):

There aren't any other read only recovery mediums that I know of but you can try [encrypting](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/secure-your-usb-drives-with-bitlocker-to-go-for-windows-7/) your usb so that nobody can overwrite the information on it without knowing the password. You could also do the same with a portable hard drive which is a little easier to differentiate from most usb drives ;).

Comment: This won't work. Anyone will be able to format that USB anyway if the device is connected to Linux machine or if the auto run is blocked